# 2 buttons, 1 servo, turn when pressed only

Tags: programming

I have a code problem. I need to turn a servo clockwise or counter clockwise using 2 microswitches.

The problem is that my code is fine on startup, but when i press the button the servo continues to spin.

How do i make this so it only spins while the buttons are pressed and turn off when they are not pressed?

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo; // create servo object to control a servo

// CONSTANTS

// PINS
const int crServo = 12; // sets pin 12 as servo
const int buttonPinCW = 2; // sets pin 2 as button; CW => clockwise => FOCUS FAR
const int buttonPinCC = 3; // sets pin 3 as button; CC => counterclockwise => FOCUS NEAR

// SERVO PROPERTIES
const int crSpeedDefault = 0; // is the stay still position, motor should not turn
const int crSpeedCW = 110; // turns the motor full speed clockwise
const int crSpeedCC = 70; // turns the motor full speed counter-clockwise

// SET BUTTON STATES
int buttonStateCW = 0; //sets button 1 as off
int buttonStateCC = 0; // sets button 2 as off

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(crServo); // attaches the servo on pin 12 to the servo object
  pinMode (crServo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (buttonPinCW, INPUT); // sets button as input
  pinMode (buttonPinCC, INPUT); // sets button as input
  myservo.write(crSpeedDefault); // default servo to crSpeedDefault
}

void loop()
{
  crServo = digitalRead(crSpeedDefault);
  buttonStateCW = digitalRead(buttonPinCW);
  buttonStateCC = digitalRead(buttonPinCC);
  // clockwise rotation
  if (buttonStateCW == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(crSpeedCW);
    // counterclockwise rotation
  } 
  if (buttonStateCC == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(crSpeedCC);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an external pull-down on your buttons?

Comment: Hi Maximilian, Yes, i have a wheel which spins manually by a user. The idea is that when the steering wheel spins 180 degrees a microswitch is pushed. This turns the servo one direction, the opposite is to turn the servo in the opposite direction.

Comment: I meant a pull-down resistor. Your firmware logic is that if the button pin reads "HIGH" it is pressed. Thus you must have a button via pull-down to GND and other side to +5V connected right? Also: Why is the line `crServo = digitalRead(crSpeedDefault);` there? With `const int crServo = 12` the variable cannot be changed. It doesn't make sense to re-write the servo pin to 0 or 1 using the result of `digitalRead`, which reads from pin 0 which is the Serial TX of the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the logic "if none of the two buttons are pressed, stop the servo immediately", then you'd express this in your `loop` as a `if` expression where you check if both buttons read `LOW`:

```
void loop()
{
  buttonStateCW = digitalRead(buttonPinCW);
  buttonStateCC = digitalRead(buttonPinCC);
  // clockwise rotation
  if (buttonStateCW == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(crSpeedCW);
    // counterclockwise rotation
  } 
  if (buttonStateCC == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(crSpeedCC);
  }

  //Are both buttons not pressed? 
  if(buttonStateCC == LOW && buttonStateCW == LOW) {
    //Stop the servo.
    myservo.write(0);
  }
}
```

This assumes your buttons are with pull-down resistors to GND on one side and with +5V on the other side, as detailed in the [Arduino tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button). In short this means that an unpressed button reads as `0` and a pressed on reads as `1` (`HIGH`). This is unusual because we usually use the internal pullup resistors via the `INPUT_PULLUP` `pinMode` parameter with a switched logic (`1` = unpressed, `0` = pressed).

I've also removed the line `crServo = digitalRead(crSpeedDefault);` because that doesn't make sense in my opinion, as I've detailed in my comment.

Comment: thank you, Maximilian i think this must be in my switch wiring, the code edit you sent makes them spin continuously in either direction when the button is pressed. I think i need to have a look at quite how i wire these up to the Uno as something is a-miss here i think.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your circuit then.

Comment: sorry for the delay, ok the buttons go to GND and to the input pins 2 & 3 (there are 2 buttons 1 to 2 and 1 to 3)

Comment: then the servo comes off 12 and is also connected to GND and +5v

Comment: @Richard When you edit your question you will notice a "Schematic" tool button with which you can accurately present your circuit.

Comment: @Richard there was a copy-paste error in my answer in the if-statement which may have caused the fail. Retry please.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to @Maximilian Gerhardt's solution. So his comments on the pull-up/down resistors apply.

I assume that you only want to turn either CW or CC and not oscillate between the two.

Then you should cater for 4 button conditions:
None pressed, CW only press, CC only press, both pressed.

We only need to worry about the "only pressed" conditions and a default state when coding.

Here is my solution:

```
void loop()
{
  buttonStateCW = digitalRead(buttonPinCW);
  buttonStateCC = digitalRead(buttonPinCC);

  // CW button pressed only
  if (buttonStateCW == HIGH && buttonStateCC == LOW) {
    myservo.write(crSpeedCW); // clockwise rotation
  }
  // CC button pressed only
  else if (buttonStateCW == LOW && buttonStateCC == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(crSpeedCC); // counterclockwise rotation
  }
  // Default condition
  else {
    myservo.write(crSpeedDefault);
  }
}
```